# Read json file from project in JDeveloper - Oracle MAF project

Tags: java, json, file, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am trying to read a json file into an Oracle MAF project written in JDeveloper 12c. In this kind of project, we have two main folders: ApplicationController and ViewController. My java class is in the ApplicationController folder, and my resource is also there, in public_html folder. I tried everything I found online, but nothing seems to work for me...

So the java class is rooted like this: **\myProject\ApplicationController\adfmsrc\application\MyJavaClass.java**

The json file is rooted like this:
**\myProject\ApplicationController\public_html\json\myJsonFile.json**

In my java class I added a function like the following, in order to read the file from project:

```
public static String loadJSONFromProject(String filename) {
    String json = "";
    try {
            InputStream is = Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

The way I tried to call the method is like this:

```
Utils.loadJSONFromProject("/json/myJsonFile.json");

Utils.loadJSONFromProject("json/myJsonFile.json");

Utils.loadJSONFromProject("../json/myJsonFile.json");
```

When I run the project, I get a

> java.lang.NullPointerException error on line : int size = is.available();

That means that the file wasn't found. The Utils class is the java class that contains the method from above.

Please help  me with this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it work like this:

In the folder **\myProject\ApplicationController\adfmsrc** I added a new folder called "json" where I added my file.

I went to project in JDeveloper, right click on it, then selected "Project Properties". Click on "Compiler". On the field that has the label "Copy File Types to Output Directory:" I added the ".json" extension.

After that, I called in the function above, like this: **Utils.loadJSONFromProject("../json/myJsonFile.json");** and it worked like a charm.

Thank you and I hope my answer will be helpful for others, too.